# Tomcat won't point to new port after changing in server.xml

Tags: tomcat8, openkm

Changed the port from 8080 to 9090. But still it pointing to 8080

```
<Connector port="9090" address="0.0.0.0" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443">
</Connector>
```

[Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDxN1.png)

Comment: Did you restart Tomcat after making this change?

Comment: Yes, I did restart the Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem. I was referring to wrong folder("C:\tomcat-8.5.24\conf") instead of "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\conf"

OpenKM installed Tomcat in "C:\tomcat-8.5.24". So when I tried to access http:localhost:8080/OpenKM, it was saying someone is already using port 8080.

So I was making changes to "C:\tomcat-8.5.24\conf\server.xml" and restarting Tomcat service instead of OpenKM service.